# What does 必死的决心 mean? Must-die determination?

Tags: translation, meaning

> 我以**必死的决心**发誓，从此绝对不会手淫<sup>[src](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/5636873100)</sup>
> I, by a **must-die determination** pledge, from now on absolutely won't masturbate.
>
> 抱着**必死的决心**去奋斗，不论前方有多大的困难<sup>[src](https://www.duanwenxue.com/article/4554107.html)</sup>
> Carrying a **must-die determination** go [and] struggle, regardless of big difficulties ahead.
>
> 我是抱着**必死的决心**来做的,求大家支持<sup>[src](https://news.changsha.cn/html/421/20120418/983154.html)</sup>
> I, carrying a **must-die determination**, come here, [and] seek everyone's support

I don't have a clear understanding of 必死的决心.  It breaks down:

- [必](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%BF%85) = must
- [死](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%AD%BB) = die
- [的](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%9A%84) turns 必死 into an adjective
- [决心](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%86%B3%E5%BF%83) = determination

So I've translated it to "must-die determination" above, but I don't really know.

**Question**: What does 必死的决心 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

必死 = certain death

决心 = determination

必死的决心 means "A determination so strong that you prepare to meet certain death to carry it out"

It is a 誇張詞 (exaggeration phrase).

Similar to "誓死" (swearing on one's own life)

You can omit "的" and say "必死决心"

Answer (score 2):

When you suppose that you would be dead in a battle anyway, what/how would you perform in it?  You would certainly be desperate, try your best to kill as much as you can and destroy as much as possible.  Metophorically，it suggests that you will do something as hard as you could. Basically，you'd be desperate to achieve what you intend to do. That is the kind  of idea the phrase expresses.